# Heroku returns Exec format error after releasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy a rails project to heroku on my mac m1.
But after releasing, I keep getting these error messages:

```
 Starting process with command `rails server -b 0.0.0.0`
 Error: Exec format error

 at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=... request_id=...
 fwd=... dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is the list of commands that I used:

```
  docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t myweb .
  docker tag myweb registry.heroku.com/myweb/web
  docker push registry.heroku.com/myweb/web
  heroku container:release web -a myweb
```

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ruby:3.0.2
#RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client

# Ensure latest packages for Yarn
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# Allow apt to work with https-based sources
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn build-essential libpq-dev

WORKDIR /myapp

COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install
RUN yarn install

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Configure the main process to run when running the image
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3316:3306"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

The `heroku run rails c` also throws `exec format error`

I'm really appreciate If you can point out what is wrong with my code. Many thanks

Comment: Is there a typo maybe `docker push registry.heroku.com/myweb.web`?

Comment: Should be `docker push registry.heroku.com/myweb/web`

Comment: You can also try to inspect the image you push: `docker inspect registry.heroku.com/myweb/web`

Comment: No sorry. It's my fault when posting question